# Creación de un ID en base de la duplicidad de varias columnas en Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo esto código de pandas en Python3 que crea un dataframe con una columna ID que genera un número en función de que si los valores de 2 columnas específicas de una fila ya han sido introducidos en las mismas columnas pero de otra fila, el ID se repite, pero si los valores no se han repetido se genera otro numero, esto es lo que tengo:

```
data={'Alias':[alias],'Tag':[tag],'Hostname':[hostname],'Model':[model],'User':[user],'IP':[ip],'System':[system],
        'Password':[password],'Enable_Secret':[enable_secret],'Status':[v_ping]} 

df=pd.DataFrame(data) 

df['UNIQUE_ID'] = pd.factorize(df.Hostname+df.IP)[0]
```

Este es un resultado del dataframe que se me genera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código hace esto:
Cuando los valores de las columnas Hostname e IP se repiten en otras filas, el ID se repite, si uno de los valores de Hostname o IP falta, o faltan los 2 valores, el ID es -1.

Hasta aquí bien, pero si nos damos cuenta en la columna IP se ha repetido la misma IP y el ID no se ha repetido, pasaría lo mismo si el hostname es el mismo pero la IP distinta.

Me gustaría hacer que si la IP de la nueva fila ya ha sido introducido en otra fila y aunque el hostname sea distinto que el de otras filas, el ID también se repita. Lo mismo sería para el caso del hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separando en dos métodos factorize, y buscando el mínimo entre estos dos valores, puedes conseguir lo que quieres. Me explico con código, que me resulta más facil:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Creación de un DataFrame para el ejemplo
data={
'Hostname':['hostname0','hostname0','hostname1','hostname1'],
'IP':['ip0','ip1','ip0','ip1']
} 

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

""" Factorize de 'HostName' e 'IP' por separado, 
luego búsqueda del mínimo entre los dos, 
e integración en el DataFrame """

df['Unique ID'] = [min(pd.factorize(df.Hostname)[0][index], pd.factorize(df.IP)[0][index]) for index in df.index]

# Visualización
df
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

|  | Hostname | IP | Unique ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | hostname0 | ip0 | 0 |
| 1 | hostname0 | ip1 | 0 |
| 2 | hostname1 | ip0 | 0 |
| 3 | hostname1 | ip1 | 1 |